# libvlc-qt and OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, libvlc

I'm trying to make an app using libvlc-qt and Qt5.5. Some functionalities require displyaing semi-transparent text and graphics over video widget. I've found [this](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=119301) thread, which says: "The video widget is opengl. You should be able to put a new opengl layer above."

My question is how do I approach this? I've tried creating overlapping QOpenGLWidgets and drawing using QPainter on them, and some similar simple solutions, but it resulted with nothing happening or random segfaults. Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend you try Qml with my QmlVlc lib. Please look demo: https://github.com/RSATom/QmlVlcDemo

Answer (score 0):

You can overlap `QWidget` over `QOpenGLWidget`, but not the other way around. And specifically, nothing in the parent widget and under the `QOpenGLWidget` will be visible.

Comment: both VlcVideoWidget ( does not inherit QOpenGLWidget though ) and my widget are rendered by OpenGL, so i hope for something like painting directly on video surface. Can this be done?

Comment: @rhoki You need to force Vlc to render to an off-screen framebuffer, and then you can use that framebuffer as a texture, for example. But generally speaking, separate on-screen OpenGL contexts are only composable by the desktop platform (window compositor).